# Where is the data directory from the initial Bitcoin Core Welcome prompt saved on a Mac?

Tags: bitcoin-core, mac, datadir

When you start Bitcoin Core for the first time on a Mac, you are prompted to specify a custom data directory. However, it is not clear where this setting is stored and the "Welcome" screen does not pop-up again. If you go to Options > Open Configuration File, it is empty.

I checked for the default directory of /Users/username/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin, but it doesn't exist. So where is this configuration stored?